# Which parts are missing from this vintage lockset?

Tags: doors, lock

I'd like to get this lockset back into working order on a vintage 1-3/8" interior door with 2-3/8" backset, but do not know which parts are missing. Here is what I do have:

[image]

Also, either the door has twisted, or the walls have leaned.  The door matches the stop fine on the hinge side and on the topside.  There is no threshold.  The bottom of the door on the lockset side stays away from the door-stop by 9/16".  The painted door has a single flat panel in the frame.  I suspect the panel is plywood.  My thoughts for fixing this is to either cut a tapered filler strip to fill the gap between the door and the door stop, or cut one of the corner mortise/tenon joints in the door frame and re-glue with a counter-twist and kerf-filling dutchman, maybe spline the bottom.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I can only wish you the best of luck in finding those vintage missing parts. When I was doing some renovation and have tried similar thing I ended up with changing the door :)

Comment: How much pressure does it take to push the lower corner of the door in so that it is up against the stop?

Comment: There are ways to patch doors if you do need to replace the lock,  if you don't object to a "decorative" brass plate.

Comment: @diyer If you'd like to merge your accounts, which will allow you to edit your posts and reply to answers and comments on it, select "contact us" at the bottom of the page and then "I need to merge user profiles" from the drop down.

Comment: @MichaelKaras See reply to you in a suggested edit: http://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28539

Comment: It sounds like you have two separate questions here, please consider asking a new question about straightening out the door.

Answer (score 1):

I too wish you luck.

The parts you show are made from 'pot metal.'

Such parts have a short life in the best of times.

For older hardware on the cheap, I think ebay,

the ReBuilding Center in Portland http://rebuildingcenter.org/

or somewhere from here http://portlandonthecheap.com/homeimprovement.html would likely be your best chance

Answer (score 1):

You definitely would not find any replacement parts for that passage set at a home improvement store. Unfortunately, you may not have luck finding a replacement online either because there are such a wide variety of manufacturers, as well as models. If you could find the name of the manufacturer, it would give you a fighting chance in being able to restore it. The escutcheon plate is an Art Deco design, which means the passage set was most likely manufactured in the beginning of the 20th Century.

There may be an architectural salvage yard located near you. These places have a wide array of building materials which have been salvaged from demolished buildings and remodels. This would be a good starting point since the staff are usually quite knowledgeable, and would either be able to locate a replacement, or at least give you some information on it.

It would be a good idea to find a complete example instead of replacement parts if possible. That way you can ensure that it will operate properly. You can always keep the parts you have as replacements just in case you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The part which are missing from this "lockset" -- are anything resembling a lock. Did you mean knobset?

Frankly, I'd rescue the knobs and the decorative escutcheon plates, and obtain a new mortise knobset or lockset for them to operate.

Comment: The hole to the right of the doorknob hole in the top center piece looks like it could be for a lock button, and the tiny hole in the top right piece could be to unlock it.

Comment: Good observation; this probably was a "privacy" latch originally. I can't tell from this photo whether the piece which performed that function is present, never mind intact.